# Left join reducing the number of rows returned

Tags: mysql

I want to count the number of times a behaviour happens in an hour before an event. This requires joining two tables. The first table has the time of the event and the time of an hour prior, the second table has each instance of a behaviour timestamped.

I am currently trying to join the tables with a left join, but because of the WHERE command used to specify to only count the behaviours within the hour period I think it is reducing the number of rows returned. I would like a count for the number of the behaviours in the hour prior to the event even if it is zero.

My code looks something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.*, 
COUNT(Table2.`BehaviourTime`) AS CountBefore

FROM Table1

LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.`Date` = Table2.`Date` AND Table1.`GroupRef` = 
Table2.`GroupRef`

WHERE Table2.`BehaviourTime` BETWEEN Table1.`HourBefore` AND 
Table1.`EventTime`

GROUP BY `Date`, `GroupRef`, `Session`
```

I am expecting a count for each row of Table1 (as each row represents an event), but am getting fewer rows returned each time. I need to do similar variations of this for different behaviours.

Is there a problem with my code, or a simpler way for me to get the output required without losing data?

Thanks for you help!

---

UPDATE

Expected result (1917 rows returned):

```
Session    Date    GroupRef HourBefore  EventTime   CountBefore
A          1/1/19  XX       09:32:46    10:32:46    3  
P          1/1/19  XX       15:55:02    16:55:02    0
A          4/1/19  XX       06:49:12    07:49:12    8
....
```

Actual result is returning 1306 rows, with no counts of zero.

```
Session    Date    GroupRef HourBefore  EventTime   CountBefore
A          1/1/19  XX       09:32:46    10:32:46    3  
A          4/1/19  XX       06:49:12    07:49:12    8
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add  the condition for left joined  table to the on clause

```
SELECT Table1.*, 
COUNT(Table2.`BehaviourTime`) AS CountBefore
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.`Date` = Table2.`Date` AND Table1.`GroupRef` = 
Table2.`GroupRef`  
     AND Table2.`BehaviourTime` BETWEEN Table1.`HourBefore` AND  Table1.`EventTime`
GROUP BY `Date`, `GroupRef`, `Session`
```

Otherwise  if you leave the condition related  to the left join table 's columns in   where clause  these work as INNER JOIN

For the = 0 values of CountBefore could be you need  a ifnull check

```
SELECT Table1.*, ifnull(COUNT(Table2.`BehaviourTime`),0) AS CountBefore
FROM Table1

LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.`Date` = Table2.`Date` 
    AND Table1.`GroupRef` = Table2.`GroupRef`
      AND Table2.`BehaviourTime` 
          BETWEEN Table1.`HourBefore` AND Table1.`EventTime`
GROUP BY `Date`, `GroupRef`, `Session`
```

Or try using sum for checked  if null

```
SELECT Table1.*
    , sum(case when table2.`BehaviourTime` is null then 0 else 1 end ) AS CountBefore
FROM Table1

LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.`Date` = Table2.`Date` 
    AND Table1.`GroupRef` = Table2.`GroupRef`
      AND Table2.`BehaviourTime` 
          BETWEEN Table1.`HourBefore` AND Table1.`EventTime`
GROUP BY `Date`, `GroupRef`, `Session`
```

Comment: Edit - I have managed to fix the issue with the counts and am now getting counts of zero, but still not having the correct number of rows returned

Comment: @sciasEdge I managed to sort out the issue before I saw your comment as posted above. Using SUM as you suggested was returning incorrect behaviour counts and still too few rows

Comment: be sure that the number of you think should be returned don't aggregated  by group by  ... so you should check if in group by result  .. there are all the value for table1 at least